# Importing a text file in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, import, sdk, text-files

I've been trying to read a file for the last few days and have tried following other answers but have not succeeded. This is the code I currently have to import the text file:

```
    public ArrayList<String> crteDict() {

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
                (new FileReader("/program/res/raw/levels.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] linewrds = line.split(" ");
            words.add(linewrds[0].toLowerCase());
           // process the line.
        }
        br.close();


       }
     catch (FileNotFoundException fe){
        fe.printStackTrace();
```

It is meant to read the text file and just create a long Array of words. It keeps ending up in the FileNotFoundException. 
Please let me know any answers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IF your file is stored in the `res/raw` folder of the android project, you can read it as follows, this code must be inside an `Activity` class, as `this.getResources()` refers to `Context.getResources()`:

```
// The InputStream opens the resourceId and sends it to the buffer
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.levels);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String readLine = null;

try {
    // While the BufferedReader readLine is not null 
    while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("TEXT", readLine);
}

// Close the InputStream and BufferedReader
is.close();
br.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It does not have to be inside an Activity, since you can pass a Context to whatever method does this. I would suggest you change that part. Also I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Answer. It tells me that getResource is undefined for this type. Do you know how I fix that?

Comment: As i mentioned above, `this` refers to a `Context` object. Where are you adding this code? Use `<ActivityName>.this.getResources()` or `getContext().getResources()` or if nothing works post your code / give me more info. Also its `getResources()` with a `s` in the end